# OWIN cookie authentication without ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC 5 and I'm finding very uncomfortable with Identity authentication + authorization framework. I know this is a new feature of the ASP.NET MVC framework, so I'd like to apply an alternative way to implement authentication in m y application.

Is it possible? I read I could use the `FormsAuthenticationModule`. Is this a good alternative? How can I use it in a MVC 5 based application?

Comment: The point of the OWin authentication framework is that it's completely modular. Just run `Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies` and install it on your `IAppBuilder`.

Comment: Why do you not want to use Identity? OWIN is a new way of injecting your Authentication. If you don't like it, build your own OWIN module and inject that one? Identity is the new way for authenticating users. If you don't like the whole social authentication piece, then don't use it. FormsAuthentication is a way but old.

Comment: kindly check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26485575/ it might help you

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I felt the same way when taking a look at Identity. It adds lots of unnecessary  abstractions and does not suit with my case that I have legacy system which implemented customised authentication work-flow.

Tons of examples out there about OWIN authentication using Identity and EF by default which makes developers confused that OWIN has to go with Identity and Entity Framework.

But technically, you are able to strip out Identity to use only OWIN cookie authentication (`Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies`). The code turns out very simple, below is example I got from my code which eliminates trivial things:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    var user = _userService.GetByEmail(model.Email);

    //check username and password from database, naive checking: 
    //password should be in SHA
    if (user != null && (user.Password == model.Password)) 
    {
        var claims = new[] {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Name),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email),
                // can add more claims
            };

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "ApplicationCookie");

        // Add roles into claims
        var roles = _roleService.GetByUserId(user.Id);
        if (roles.Any())
        {
            var roleClaims = roles.Select(r => new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, r.Name));
            identity.AddClaims(roleClaims);
        }

        var context = Request.GetOwinContext();
        var authManager = context.Authentication;

        authManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties 
               { IsPersistent = model.RememberMe }, identity);

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    // login failed.            
}

public ActionResult LogOut()
{
    var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
    var authManager = ctx.Authentication;

    authManager.SignOut("ApplicationCookie");
    return RedirectToAction("Login");
}
```

Comment: thank you guy, this is just perfect! but... I need to handle roles for users, is it possible using your approach?

Comment: @davioooh: yes, can handle roles like forms authentications, I updated my code to add more roles into claims

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much indeed!

Comment: Nice and concise.

Comment: @cuongle **No owin.Environment item was found in the context.** error is thrown. Any idea? I look at workarounds, but not worked none of them.

Answer (score 1):

Without Using Owin Security Methods:
Itz My Controller Coding

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(Employee emp, string returnUrl)
           {
            using(AdaptiveProjectEntities db = new AdaptiveProjectEntities())
            {
                string email = emp.Email;
               // byte[] en = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(emp.Password);
                //var ee = Convert.ToBase64String(en);
                string pass = emp.Password;

                bool userValid = db.Employees.Any(user => user.Email == email && user.Password == pass);
                    if(userValid)
                    {
                        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(email, false);



                         if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                    && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Projects");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
                    }



            return View(emp); 

       }
        public ActionResult Logout()
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Login");
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
<div class="container" style="margin-right:50%">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-7" style="bottom:-250px">
           <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-right:15%">
                <div class="panel-heading" style="padding-bottom:5%">

                    <center><h3 style="margin-right:80px">Login</h3></center>
                    @*</div>*@
                    @using (Html.BeginForm())
                    {
                        <div class="modal-body">

                            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                            <div class="form-horizontal" style="margin-right: 10%;">
                                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", type = "email", required = "required" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", type = "password", required = "required" } })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <input class="btn btn-primary pull-left col-lg-offset-1" type="submit" value="Login" style="margin-left:35%" />
                            </div>

                        </div>


                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```